# Get one, random object from object array and display on page

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**TL;DR** = I need to display one, random object from the `ads` array

I have an array of objects:

```
{
    "ads": [
        {
            "adLogo": "src/img/ads/ad1.png",
            "adCompany": "Ad Company 1",
            "adBackgroundColor": "#1e64f0",
            "adDescription": "Ad company 1 is awesome",
            "adLink": "ad_company1_link_goes_here"
        },
        {
            "adLogo": "src/img/ads/ad2.png",
            "adCompany": "Ad Company 2",
            "adBackgroundColor": "#1e64f0",
            "adDescription": "Ad company 2 is awesome",
            "adLink": "ad_compan21_link_goes_here"
        },
    ]
}
```

and I have this code to display a value from the JSON:

```
fetch("src/js/_ads.json")
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
          });

        function appendData(data) {
          let mainContainer = document.getElementById("ad-block");
          for (let i = 0; i = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length); i++) {
            let adLink = data[i].adLink;
            let adDesc = data[i].adDescription;
            let adLogo = data[i].adLogo;
            let adCompany = data[i].adCompany;
            let adBackground = data[i].adBackgroundColor;
            document.querySelector("#ad-block").innerHTML +=
              `
            <a href="${adLink}" target="_blank" id="ad-click">
              <div class="ad__banner ad__banner--dark ad__banner--column">
              <div class="ad__image" style="background-color: ${adBackground}">
                <img src="${adLogo}" alt="sponsored by ${adCompany}">
              </div>
              <div class="ad__desc">
                <div class="ad__tagline">${adDesc}</div>
                <div class="ad__button" style="background-color: var(--gray-700)">Start Free Trial</div>
                <div class="ad__sponsored"><strong style="color: ${adBackground}">${adCompany}</strong> Affiliate</div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </a>
                `;
          }
        }
```

I had some code to get a random value `Math.floor(Math.random() *` but it ended up displaying all of the objects vs just one, random object.

Comment: Please include your code using `Math.random()` in your post.

Comment: @mykaf - updated w/ `Math.random()`

Comment: Just don't loop: `let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);   let adLink = data[rnd].adLink;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through all the objects in the array, you just need to generate a random index and display the object.

```
function appendData(data) {
  let mainContainer = document.getElementById("ad-block");
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.ads.length);
  let adLink = data.ads[randomIndex].adLink;
  let adDesc = data.ads[randomIndex].adDescription;
  let adLogo = data.ads[randomIndex].adLogo;
  let adCompany = data.ads[randomIndex].adCompany;
  let adBackground = data.ads[randomIndex].adBackgroundColor;
  document.querySelector("#ad-block").innerHTML +=
    `
    <a href="${adLink}" target="_blank" id="ad-click">
      <div class="ad__banner ad__banner--dark ad__banner--column">
      <div class="ad__image" style="background-color: ${adBackground}">
        <img src="${adLogo}" alt="sponsored by ${adCompany}">
      </div>
      <div class="ad__desc">
        <div class="ad__tagline">${adDesc}</div>
        <div class="ad__button" style="background-color: var(--gray-700)">Start Free Trial</div>
        <div class="ad__sponsored"><strong style="color: ${adBackground}">${adCompany}</strong> Affiliate</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </a>
        `;
}
```